# How to extract text from quoted string with regex in java?

Tags: java, regex, csv

I have a String like this:

```
"0008934","1801 W NORMATOWN ROAD","ROMEOVILLE","IL","US","60446","8158866981","Y"
```

I would like to extract all the values inside double quotes. Could you please help me to accomplish the task.

This is what I am expecting:

```
0008934
1801 W NORMATOWN ROAD
ROMEOVILLE
IL
US
60446
8158866981
Y
```

Anyone can you pleas help me?

Comment: Use `()` to group anything inside `""` and then use `Matcher#find()` and `Matcher#group()`

Comment: Is the input CSV? If so you need to handle escaped quotes, or better yet use a proper CSV parser.

Comment: I am using java code only...

Answer (score 6):

You can do like this:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class RegexTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strInput = "\"0008934\",\"1801 W NORMATOWN ROAD\",\"ROMEOVILLE\",\"IL\",\"US\",\"60446\",\"8158866981\",\"Y\"";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(strInput);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
0008934
1801 W NORMATOWN ROAD
ROMEOVILLE
IL
US
60446
8158866981
Y
```

Comment: 1 minute and 9 sec to the response, really fast ;) +1

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to consider [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/), a light-weight and simple open-source library consisting of only a few Java classes. Since your input is CSV, OpenCSV can do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use strip the leading and trailing quotes, then split on `","`

```
String[] parts = input.replaceAll("(^\")|(\"$)", "").split("\",\"");
```

Comment: This approach forbids the use of escaped quotes in the values.

Comment: @Thomas That's true, but his example did not have one, and I thought if it was important he would surely have included one

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a problem and try to solve it with a regex, you have two problems.
Consider this:

```
String[] list = input.split(",");  
foreach (String str : list){  
    str.replaceAll("\"","");
}
```

Comment: , (comma) cannot be used within the values with this approach

Comment: @JavaMentor, from the example you can't tell it should be.

Comment: yes, you are right, but this is quite common with addresses right? And the sample was an address

Comment: @JavaMentor, yep, but that's up to OP to decide.